# customizing ios Passbook with Image

Tags: image, passbook

I have a Requirement where is should show a image where barcode is place in passbook, Is there any way that i could replace barcode with image or remove barcode and make a background image not blurr or place image on back side of passbook ,As per Apple documentation it seems like I can not do it,Still wanted to check if any one can help me in any way that i can reach the requirement .

Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly it's not possible to do those things.

However, you could put an image into the strip position of the pass without putting any text over it.

I use this to place a 1D barcode on Passes (makemeapass.azurewebsites.net) and it works quite well.

What are you tying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for response ,I am trying to show company id card on the passbook which is an image I thought of placing in strip but that seems too small as per height so thinking to find more options.

Comment: Do you mean an individual's photo or the logo of a company? Would the Thumbnail image be suitable?